# bcrypt-node is throwing error "No callback function was given"

Tags: node.js, passport.js, jwt

I am creating a user registration using JWT authentication. and I am using bcrypt-node module to make password hash and salted.

**useraModel.js**

```
var mongoose    =require('mongoose');
var Schema      =mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt      =require('bcrypt-node');

var UserSchema=new Schema({
    name:{type:String, unique:true, required:true},
    password:{type:String, required:true}
});

    UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
        var user = this;
        if (this.isModified('password') || this.isNew) {
            bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }
                bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
                    if (err) {
                        return next(err);
                    }
                    user.password = hash;
                    next();
                });
            });
        } else {
            return next();
        }
    });

    UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (passw, cb) {
        bcrypt.compare(passw, this.password, function (err, isMatch) {
            if (err) {
                return cb(err);
            }
            cb(null, isMatch);
        });
    };

    module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**passport.js**

```
var JwtStrategy     =require('passport-jwt').Strategy; 
var User                =require('../app/models/user');
var config            =require('../config/database');

module.exports=function(passport){
      var opts = {}; 
  opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.id}, function(err, user) {
          if (err) {
              return done(err, false);
          }
          if (user) {
              done(null, user);
          } else {
              done(null, false);
          }
      });
  }));
};
```

**app.js**

```
apiRoutes.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.name || !req.body.password) {
     res.json({success: false, msg: 'Please pass name and password.'});
         } else {
                var newUser = new User({
                                 name: req.body.name,
                                 password: req.body.password
                         });
    // save the user
        newUser.save(function(err) {
         if (err) {
                 return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Username already exists.'});
                }
                res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user.'});
                });
             }
        });
```

When I run this code its showing error-

```
throw "No callback function was given".

No Callback function was given
```

Please help me to fix this code.
Thanks

Comment: Need the stack trace in your question and a way to figure out line numbers in your code.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`bcrypt.hash()`](https://github.com/shaneGirish/bcrypt-nodejs#api) requires 4 arguments:

```
hash(data, salt, progress, cb)
```

The documentation is unclear on this: it states that `data`, `salt` and `cb` are required, which implies that `progress` isn't, but without it you'll get the error.

Pass a `null` if you don't care about tracking progress:

```
bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function (err, hash) { ... })
```

Comment: Thanks a ton..  `null` is working for me.. Now user is creating successfully.

Comment: bcrypt-node looks inactive.. ?  but bcrypt looks active https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/, but a lot of bugs, wich are you using please ?

Answer (score 1):

No callback function was given, add null for not return callback !

for example:

```
bcrypt.hash(password, salt, null, (err, hash)
```

My router:

```
router.post('/create/', (req, res) => {

    const email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);

    let errors = [];
    if (errors.length > 0) {

    } else {
        if (email) {
            pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email],
                (err, results) => {
                    if (results.length > 0) {
                        res.status(400);
                        res.json({ Return: req.body.email + " Já existe no Banco de dados" })
                    } else {
                        bcrypt.hash(password, salt, null, (err, hash) => {
                            req.body.password = hash
                            pool.query('INSERT INTO users( email, password) VALUES(?, ?)', [req.body.email, hash]);
                            res.status(200);
                            res.json({ Send: results })
                        })
                    }
                });
        } else {
            res.send('Enter Email');
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29977418)